# How to correctly assert values returned by Number.prototype.toLocaleString("sv-SE")?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, locale

While writing tests for a value formatter service I noticed that there is something odd about `Number.prototype.toLocaleString("sv-SE")`.

```js
let myValue = (100000).toLocaleString("sv-SE");

console.log(typeof myValue);
console.log(myValue);
console.log(myValue === "100 000"); // false, why?
```

I expect the last log statement to return `true`. But it does not, why?

Comment: That character is [U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). Not a normal space character ([U+0020](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)).

Comment: Right, got it, just need to use the correct space character. What don't you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the "space character" is actually [U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). This character looks exactly like a normal space but isn't applicable for end-of-line word-wrap algorithms.

The following code works as expected:

```js
let myValue = (100000).toLocaleString("sv-SE");

console.log(typeof myValue);
console.log(myValue);
console.log(myValue === "100\u00a0000");
```